# How to get all posts that a user voted on?

Tags: support, api, users, voting

I know how to get all questions that I favorited using [/docs/me-favorites](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-favorites).
But, how can I get all answers (or questions) that I voted on? Like those in the upvote history.

Comment: Short answer is: You can't.  For your own votes, you may scrape the vote tab on your user page.  For other users, it is not possible unless you hack their account (not recommended).

Comment: Thank you! I got it. I just don't understand why they don't provide such basic api.